# How to setup passenger/nginx for dev/prod, same rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I need to setup nginx in a way that I can use the same rails app in both dev an prod modes.

For example, when I access http://mysite it should run in production mode, and when I access http://dev.mysite or http://mysite:3000 it should run in development mode.

I tried many configurations but they didn't work. Both URLs always take me to the same enviroment.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mysite;
root /srv/www/mysite/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_user mysite;
rails_env production;
}

server {
listen 3000;
server_name mysite;
root /srv/www/mysite/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_user mysite;
rails_env development;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not possible to use both urls at the same time with different enviroments.

The solution is to use the url corresponding to the environment needed, and then when you want to switch environments, restart the application and use the other url

```
$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```